# mostrar la misma información en tiempo real

Tags: angular13

Estoy haciendo una página web en angular, que es una lotería, necesito mostrar la misma información a todos los usuarios, es un tipo de lotería que se jugará en tiempo real, es decir, cuando se muestren los números ganadores, todos ve lo mismo en tiempo real cuando juegas a la lotería

esta es mi ruleta de números que gira y va mostrando los números que son ganadores, necesito que este resultado se vea reflejado igual a todos los usuarios ejemplo: si el sorteo es de cuatro números, y un usuario ingresa a mitad del sorteo y ya hay dos números del sorteo reflejados que este usuario vea esta información actualizada,

```js
<--app-component-->
export class PlayRaffleComponent implements OnInit {

isVisible: boolean = false;
  text: any = 'INICIAR'; 

  constructor( private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
     private _resultsService: RaffleResultService,) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  toggle() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;

  }

  onCompleted() {
    console.log("Emit onCompleted");
  }
 
}



 <--ruleta-component-->
 
 
 export class ValidationFieldComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {
  @ViewChild("canvas", { static: false })
  canvas!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  ctx: any = CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  raffleNameData: any;
  // The inputs and outputs
  @Input() number!: string;
  @Input() raffleDate!: any;
  @Input() raffleNameId!: any; // The value you want to animate - The message displayed
  @Input() options: any = {}; // options to configure
  @Output() completed = new EventEmitter<void>(); // onComplete emit done

  // Config options
  text: any = [];
  chars = [..."01234567890[]\'"]; // All possible Charactrers
  scale = 60; // Font size and overall scale
  breaks = 0.003; // Speed loss per frame
  endSpeed = 0.05; // Speed at which the letter stopps
  firstLetter = 620; // Number of frames untill the first letter stopps (60 frames per second)
  delay = 500; // Number of frames between letters stopping

  // Non config options
  charMap: any = [];
  offset: any = [];
  offsetV: any = [];

  myRequestId: any;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone,
    private _resultsService: RaffleResultService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkMessage();
    this.addSettings();

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("afterViewInit");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
    this.animate();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.myRequestId);
    console.log("onDestroy");
  }
 
  private checkMessage() {
    console.log('number', this.number);
    if (this.number) {
      this.text = [...this.number.toUpperCase()]
    }

  }
  play(){
    this.addSettings();
  }
  private addSettings(): void {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.chars.length; i++) {
      this.charMap[this.chars[i]] = i;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++) {
      var f = this.firstLetter + this.delay * i;
      this.offsetV[i] = this.endSpeed + this.breaks * f;
      this.offset[i] = (-(1 + f) * (this.breaks * f + 2 * this.endSpeed)) / 2;
    }
  }

  private animate(): void {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.myRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(() => this.step());
    });
  }

  private step(): void {
    this.ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.width, this.ctx.canvas.height);
    this.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#622"; // the focus point colour
    this.ctx.fillRect(
      0,
      (this.ctx.canvas.height - this.scale) / 2,
      this.ctx.canvas.width,
      this.scale
    );
    let running = false; // this flag to stop requestAnimationFrame
    for (var i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++) {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "#ccc"; // text colour
      this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      this.ctx.textAlign = "center";
      this.ctx.setTransform(
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        Math.floor(
          (this.ctx.canvas.width - this.scale * (this.text.length - 1)) / 2
        ),
        Math.floor(this.ctx.canvas.height / 2)
      );
      var o = this.offset[i];
      while (o < 0) o++;
      o %= 1;
      var h = Math.ceil(this.ctx.canvas.height / 2 / this.scale);
      for (var j = -h; j < h; j++) {
        var c = this.charMap[this.text[i]] + j - Math.floor(this.offset[i]);
        while (c < 0) c += this.chars.length;
        c %= this.chars.length;
        var s =
          1 - Math.abs(j + o) / (this.ctx.canvas.height / 2 / this.scale + 1);
        this.ctx.globalAlpha = s;
        this.ctx.font = this.scale * s + "px Helvetica";
        // error correction if undefined show empty
        this.ctx.fillText(this.chars[c] || '', this.scale * i, (j + o) * this.scale);
      }
      this.offset[i] += this.offsetV[i];
      this.offsetV[i] -= this.breaks;
      if (this.offsetV[i] < this.endSpeed) {
        this.offset[i] = 0;
        this.offsetV[i] = 0;
      } else {
        running = true;
      }
    }
    if (running) {
      this.myRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(() => this.step());
      // console.log("myRequestId", this.myRequestId);
    } else {
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.myRequestId);
      this.completed.emit();
      console.log("onComplete");
    }
  }


}





 <--animacion.ts-->

 import { trigger, state, transition, animate, style, } from '@angular/animations';

export const AnimationDataUpdate = trigger('dataUpdate', [
    state('0', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
    })),
    state('1', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -55%)'
    })),
    state('2', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -60%)'
    })),
    state('3', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -65%)'
    })),
    state('4', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -70%)'
    })),
    state('5', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -75%)'
    })),
    state('6', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -80%)'
    })),
    state('7', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -85%)'
    })),
    state('8', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -90%)'
    })),
    state('9', style({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -95%)'
    })),
])
```

```css
canvas { 
    border-style: solid;
    background: #111; 
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<--ruleta-component.html-->

<div class="ruleta">
    <ng-container *ngIf="text; else isEmpty">
        <canvas #canvas max-width="800" max-height="600"></canvas>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #isEmpty>
        <p>sin numero</p>
      </ng-template>
</div>



<--app-component.html-->

<div class="ruleta">
  <app-validationField *ngIf="isVisible" number="{{raffleNumberPlay}}" raffleDate="{{raffleDatePlay}}" raffleNameId="{{RaffleNamePlay}}" (completed)="onCompleted()"></app-validationField>
  <button  *ngIf="isVisible" class="flex-auto" type="button" [color]="'primary'" mat-raised-button (click)="toggle()">Terminar</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Tu pregunta no incluye un problema específico ni lo que has intentado hacer. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información faltante así como el código que has intentado hacer

Comment: gracias por tu sugerencia acabo de modificar mi pregunta, espero ya sea fácil de entender lo que necesito

Comment: No olvides colocar también en el título cuál es el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo.